# How to extract error data from KeyError in python

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, keyerror

I have an excel file from which I retrieve data with `pandas`. I have a dictionary where keys are the same strings that I get from a cell from the excel file. For example, I have a excel cell that contains string `Heattreatment 1`. In my dictionary I have a key, value pair: `"Heattreatment 1": 1`. The problem is that if I have typos in my excel file, for example, if instead of `Heattreatment 1` I write `Heattreatment 123` and such a key does not exist in my dictionary, I get `KeyError: 'Heattreatment 123'`.

Is there a way to extract this message, so that I would say something like:

```
error_data = #something
print(error_data)
```

And the output would be:
`'Heattreatment 123'`

I tried:

```
try:
    # some code
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

But this does not work.

Comment: You say you want the output to be `'Heattreatment 123'` but that's exactly what `print(e)` outputs already. Demo: https://ideone.com/Oua7PP Please clarify what you mean by "But this does not work", or post your actual code instead of `# some code`.

Answer (score 0):

Your last example should work if you catch KeyError specifically instead of the general Exception. When possible you should catch as specific of an error as possible.

```
try:
    # some code
except KeyError as error:
    print(error)
```

If your goal is to reconstruct the actual error message itself, this would also work just by catching the KeyError and reconstructing the message.

```
try:
    # some code
except KeyError as error:
    print(f"KeyError: '{error}'")
```